# How to print multiple iterations of the same sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a one pager that I have built for work that pulls data for specific stores into a one page document.  Area managers will have anywhere from 10-15 stores that they cover.  I would like to write a macro that allows them to select their area, run the one pager for each store within their area, then essentially append that to a list of sheets to print.  The result I am looking for is a 10 - 15 page document laying out the one pager for each of the managers stores.

I have done a decent amount of research and haven't been able to find anything to this effect.  I am not asking for someone to write the code for me, I just need a high level overview of 1) if this task is even possible to automate, and 2) what resources to use to learn how to do it.  I appreciate any help you may have to offer!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a userform to select the specific region.  From there a macro could run your one pager for each of the defined stores in that region and place each one pager in a new worksheet as it went through the list. At the end you would have one workbook with 10-15 sheets. You can then either print or export the entire workbook.

Is that in the ballpark of what you were looking for?